# Why doesn't saturation photocurrent depend on frequency of incident ray, keeping intensity constant?

Tags: photoelectric-effect

We know that intensity I = nhf, where n is no. of photons striking metal surface per second per unit sq unit area, and f is frequency of incident ray. In the book it was said that if we change the frequency of the incident keeping intensity constant, the saturation current doesn't vary.

But if intensity I is constant, then the quantity n should also change inversely with changing f, (since I= nhf). As a result, saturation current (which depends on n) should vary too. Why does this not happen?

Comment: What circuit are you asking about? What is causing it to saturate?

Comment: @thephoton here's a photo: http://ibphysicsstuff.wdfiles.com/local--files/quantum-mechanics/PhotoElectric1.jpg    and saturation is achieved when each incident photon liberates exactly 1 photon

Comment: [Duplicate here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/244660/photoelectric-effect-why-is-the-saturation-current-the-same-as-you-vary-the-fr?rq=1).